# Send data to server from JavaScript to PHP, getting 500 Error

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, ajax

I've been looking for code examples or methods to send data from my web to the server database.

After find some options, I decided to make an ajax call to send the data. the code is:
the html:

```
<form name="form" method="post">
                <p> xxxxxx </p>
                <input type="text" id="xxxxxx" class="textInput"/>
                <p> yyyyyy </p>
                <input type="text" id="yyyyyy" class="dateForm" />
                <p> zzzzzz </p>
                <input type="text" id="zzzzzz" class="dateForm" />
                <input type="image" src="img/submit.png" class="addButton" name="Añadir"/>
    </form>
```

the jquery code:

```
$(document).on("click", ".addButton", function(){

        var json = {"xxxxxx": $("#xxxxx").val(),
                    "yyyyyy": $("#yyyyyy").val(),
                    "zzzzzz": $("#zzzzzz").val()};

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'scripts/sendData.php',
            data: {param1: json},
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){
            }
        });

    });
```

and php code:

```
<?php

    $db = ***connection parameters***;
    $c1 = oci_connect(***connection parameters***);

    if($c1){

        $myJson = json_decode($_POST['param1']);
            $xxxxxx=  $myJson['xxxxxx'];
            $yyyyyy=  $myJson['yyyyyy'];
            $zzzzzz=  $myJson['zzzzzz'];

            $sql = "INSERT INTO table (xxxxxx, yyyyyy, zzzzzz) VALUES (:xxxxxx, 
                to_date(:yyyyyy), to_date(:zzzzzz))";
            $stid = oci_parse($c1, $sql);
            oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':xxxxxx', $xxxxxx);
            oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':yyyyyy', $yyyyyy);
            oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':zzzzzz', $zzzzzz);

            oci_execute($stid);
            oci_free_statement($stid);
            oci_close($c1);

    }
    }
    ?>
```

Debugging with chrome the json is created correctly, and the 500 error is a server error, so the error must be on php code. The connection should be ok, cause I get data from server correctly.

I've been changing the code several times looking through internet, but still can't send data :S could anyone tell where is the error?

PD: If I put an echo before if($c1){ and manually enter to the url put in the ajax method I don't get anything. does it mean something?

Thank you and regards

Comment: Where is the php code?

Comment: add the output of  `print_r($myJson);`  to your question.

Comment: Simply use action="scripts/sendData.php" in the form. It may be work

Comment: Is this your whole code on that PHP or a chunk of code? Because there is an extra curly brace in your code.

Comment: It was the whole code. I could find the logs in server and know I can see the errors. I'm trying to fix them. thanks!

Comment: Ok, apart from the extra curly brace, the way to get json parameters is: $xxxxxx =  $myJson->{'xxxxxx'}; And in one modification, I put data: {param1: json} instead of data: {param1: JSON.stringify(json)}. Now I can insert into DataBase. The thread can be closed. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

**Try some of the following:**

remove `dataType: 'json'` from ajax call

make a normal javascript Object for json var like this:

```
var json = {asdf: $("#xxxxx").val(),
            ghjk: $("#yyyyyy").val(),
            klyx: $("#zzzzzz").val()};
```

use `data: {param1: JSON.stringify(json)}`

**EDIT:**

Try to bind the ajax-post to form submit, not to the button with click, user could send form via hitting enter or something else...

```
$(document).on("submit", "form", function(){
   ....
});
```

Comment: Ok, didn't know that, I'll change it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can also pass JSON data in ajax in this way:

```
$(document).on("click", ".addButton", function(){
    var arr=new Array();
    arr.push({
       'asdf': $("#xxxxx").val()
    });
    arr.push({
       'ghjk':$("#yyyyyy").val()
    });
    arr.push({
       'klyx':$("#zzzzzz").val()
    });

    var json=JSON.stringify(arr);

    $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'scripts/sendData.php',
            data: {param1: json},
            success: function(data){
            }
    });

});
```